# I am trying to find a path through a randomly generated maze

Tags: java, swing, linked-list

This is a maze solver and I am trying to find a path through the maze. The Map is generated using Prim's algorithm and the position class which is added at the end.
I am trying to find an optimal path through the randomly generated maze using BFS, A*, or DFS but I seem to be doing something wrong.

```
    //impoted by wildcard
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    
    public class MazeGenerator extends Canvas {
    
        private final Random rand = new Random(); //random variable
        private static int WIDTH;
        private static int HEIGHT;
        private int TILE_WIDTH = 15;
        private int TILE_HEIGHT = 15;
        
        private static LinkedList <position> maze = new LinkedList<>(); // maze
        private static Map<position, Color> colors = new HashMap<>();
        
        // paint class to draw out the maze
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.translate(5, 5);
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH * TILE_WIDTH, HEIGHT * TILE_HEIGHT);
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, HEIGHT * TILE_HEIGHT);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, WIDTH * TILE_WIDTH, 0);
            g.drawLine(WIDTH * TILE_WIDTH, 0, WIDTH * TILE_WIDTH, HEIGHT * TILE_HEIGHT);
            g.drawLine(0, HEIGHT * TILE_HEIGHT, WIDTH * TILE_WIDTH, HEIGHT * TILE_HEIGHT);
            
            LinkedList <position> mazeSteped = maze;
    
            for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
                {
                    int current = (y * WIDTH) + x;
                    int lower = ((y + 1) * WIDTH) + x;
                    if(!mazeSteped.contains(new position(current, lower)))
                        g.drawLine(x * TILE_WIDTH, (y + 1) * TILE_HEIGHT, (x + 1) * TILE_WIDTH, (y + 1) * TILE_HEIGHT);
    
                    if(!mazeSteped.contains(new position(current, current + 1)))
                        g.drawLine((x + 1) * TILE_WIDTH, y * TILE_HEIGHT, (x + 1) * TILE_WIDTH, (y + 1) * TILE_HEIGHT);
    
                    if(colors.containsKey(new position(x, y)))
                    {
                        g.setColor(colors.get(new position(x, y)));
                        g.fillRect(x * TILE_WIDTH, y * TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
                        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Prim's algorithm
        public void generate(int Width, int Height)
        { 
            LinkedList<Integer> visited = new LinkedList<>();
            LinkedList<position> toVisit = new LinkedList<>();
    
            visited.add(0);
            toVisit.add(new position(0, 1));
            toVisit.add(new position(0, Width));
    
            while(toVisit.size() > 0)
            {
                int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(toVisit.size());
                position nextPath = toVisit.remove(randomIndex);
    
                if(visited.contains(nextPath.end))
                    continue;
    
                if(nextPath.start > nextPath.end)
                    maze.add(new position(nextPath.end, nextPath.start));
                else
                    maze.add(nextPath);
    
                visited.add(nextPath.end);
   
//this is showing all four directions that the random variable can generate towards.

                int above = nextPath.end - Width;
                if(above > 0 && !visited.contains(above))
                    toVisit.add(new position(nextPath.end, above));
    
                int left = nextPath.end - 1;
                if(left % Width != Width - 1 && !visited.contains(left))
                    toVisit.add(new position(nextPath.end, left));
    
                int right = nextPath.end + 1;
                if(right % Width != 0 && !visited.contains(right))
                    toVisit.add(new position(nextPath.end, right));
    
                int below = nextPath.end + Width;
                if(below < Width * Height && !visited.contains(below))
                    toVisit.add(new position(nextPath.end, below));
            }
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            MazeGenerator mazeGen = new MazeGenerator();
            int Height = 30;
            HEIGHT = Height;
            int Width = 30;
            WIDTH = Width;
            mazeGen.generate(Width, Height);
            mazeGen.setSize(16*Width, 17*Height);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maze Generator");
            frame.add(mazeGen);
            frame.setSize(16*Width, 17*Height);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }    
    }
```

```
    
    //position or vector class that keeps track of position.   
    public class position{
        public int start;
        public int end;
    
        public position(int start, int end){
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }
    
        public String toString(){
            return "(" + start + ", " + end + ")";
        }
    
        public boolean equals(Object obj){
            if(!(obj instanceof position))
                return false;
    
            position pos = (position) obj;
            return pos.start == start && pos.end == end;
        }
    
        public int hashCode(){
            return this.toString().hashCode();
        }
        
        public static void main(String [] args) {
            position my = new position(1,1);
            System.out.println(new position(1,1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Describe the results your algorithm generates. That helps to solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "I seem to be doing something wrong"? You mention BFS, DFS, and A*, but it doesn't look like you've implemented any of them, at least not in the code you've shown us.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make your code easy to read, please indent it and follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/). 
Also please explain your algorithm. Are you trying to generate and find path in one go ? Consider solving the maze after it has been generated.
One obvious problem is that you never add any value to `color`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yuchinchenTW/MazeGenerate/tree/master

try this maze generator

using depth-first search and Recursive division method

The recursive division method can prevent stackoverflow on recursion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.